# Fast iteration through DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, performance

I want to iterate through a DataFrame with a bunch of conditions on the index, which is a timestamp.

I am looking for a more efficient way to do this, as the method I have implemented is very slow (especially since I am processing 200k rows).

This is my current solution, which also gives me a warning at the line `df['WeekDay'][index] = int(index.weekday())`.

```py
import pandas as pd
from datetime import time

# Create DataFrame df...

for index in df.index:  # brute force loop through every row
    df['WeekDay'][index] = int(index.weekday())
    time_index = index.time()  # get current time out of the index
    code = 1
    if time(18, 0, 0) <= time_index < time(23, 59, 59, 999999):
        code = 1
    elif time(0, 0, 0) <= time_index < time(8, 0, 0):
        code = 1
    elif time(8, 0, 0) <= time_index < time(9, 30, 0):
        code = 2
    elif time(9, 30, 0) <= time_index < time(10, 30, 0):
        code = 3
    elif time(10, 30, 0) <= time_index < time(11, 30, 0):
        code = 4
    elif time(11, 30, 0) <= time_index < time(14, 30, 0):
        code = 5
    elif time(14, 30, 0) <= time_index < time(16, 0, 0):
        code = 6
    else:
        code = 7
    df['code'][index] = code
```

Comment: Where is your `time` function defined?

Comment: from datetime import time

Comment: Please provide a minimal example of your data.

Comment: You cannot cast `index.weekday()` to `int` this way: `int(index.weekday())`. Here, `int(x)`, `x` must be a single value, not a pandas `Series`.

Answer (score 0):

See if this works:

```py
from datetime import time

# define a function to map the time to a code
def time_to_code(t):
    if time(18, 0, 0) <= t < time(23, 59, 59, 999999):
        return 1
    elif time(0, 0, 0) <= t < time(8, 0, 0):
        return 1
    elif time(8, 0, 0) <= t < time(9, 30, 0):
        return 2
    elif time(9, 30, 0) <= t < time(10, 30, 0):
        return 3
    elif time(10, 30, 0) <= t < time(11, 30, 0):
        return 4
    elif time(11, 30, 0) <= t < time(14, 30, 0):
        return 5
    elif time(14, 30, 0) <= t < time(16, 0, 0):
        return 6
    else:
        return 7

# create a new column for the weekday code
df['WeekDayCode'] = df.index.dayofweek

# create a new column for the time code
df['TimeCode'] = df.index.time.map(time_to_code)
```